# Turning vise screws?

Tags: vises

I've been trying to wrap my head around how to turn a wooden vise screw on the lathe (around 3 to 6 TPI) . I've looked at Thread chasing and a few jigs, but the have a few problems:

The thread chasing appears to only be for small length high TPI threads

The threading jigs I've found ( purchased or otherwise appear to do short distances and high TPI as well)

The router jigs appear to be a valid option but I can't find a purchased or plans for how to attach a router to the lathe bed...

I've been looking at how it's done on a metal working lathe and it appears quite simple, the main drawback on the wood lathe is the lack of a lead screw, I have debated hooking up a stepper motor with a lead screw and attaching a cross slide vise on the lathe but it just seems like this should be easier and I'm missing something fundamental....

I basically want to have a system that will allow me to turn a wooden thread ( external AND Internal ) with relative ease and not being tied to an existing lead screw for the TPI...

I hope this makes sense and someone can point me in the right direction....

Something like this is what I'm trying to make:

[image: Wood Vice screw]
https://www.theenglishwoodworker.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/maguire-wooden-vice-screw.jpg

P.S I know I could get or make a tap and die set for wood but they are over 800 euros...

https://www.fine-tools.com/gewind.html

TL;DR is I'm trying to create a 3tpi screw vise on the wood lathe and can't figure out how to do it....

Comment: You're not alone here, you're on a path many others have trodden before you so it's not going to be difficult to find solutions. But from what I've seen the first thing you need to do is ditch the idea of using the lathe (except for turning the dowel of course). There's plenty of detail and obvious previous research in your Q (bravo for that BTW) but I think you've placed yourself behind the 8 ball thinking you can do this on the lathe. You can absolutely do this on a metalworking lathe, but they're specifically designed to allow for that sort of operation, alone with the needed toolholding.

Comment: yeah, I suspected as much... But the wood lathe is just THERE it seems like the right tool for it.... and I'm to stubborn and pig headed to back out now... I was just hoping that this wouldn't turn into a multi month project with ardunions and stepper motors..

Comment: Also some clarifying questions, are you hoping to be able to do this repeatedly or for a small number of multiples, or do you just need one threaded dowel and associated nut for a single vice? Are aesthetics important or are you okay if the result doesn't look that perfect, as long as it provides a firm grip? Does the dowel diameter matter (I mean is this a fixed requirement or do you have some wiggle room)? Last but not least, 3 TPI or just something approximately that coarse?

Comment: I love questions:
I'd love to be able to do this repeatedly, ( but realistically I need two screws for a moxon vise) 
Form follows function in my opinion, but I'd like it to not look like uttersh*t.
Dowel diameter isn't strict nor is TPI ... Just coarse and big :)

Comment: *"it seems like the right tool for it"* But what if it isn't? This is completely doable — regardless of what your requirements actually are — but just think of all the people who have done this not only without a lathe but prior to electricity.... or even steam power for that matter :-)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it hand carved but ufffff I really can't be arsed hand carving one... More than anything it's a test of ability to see if i CAN do it not _should_ I do it ;)

Comment: *"Dowel diameter isn't strict nor is TPI ... Just coarse and big :)"* That's excellent since it gives you an easy solution. No lathe, but it gets you to your end goal without it being a labour of Hercules or whatever :-) You start with acme or square threaded rod and go from there. But since the end requirement is for a twin-screw vice, does this have to be an all-wood end product? Plenty of vices like this are built with standard threaded rod (Imperial and metric) which although slow do work acceptably for the limited range of movement these are typically called on to do. Plus [contd]

Comment: ...you can even do it without screws, [comme ça](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTxo9.jpg) :-))

Comment: What do you mean by "You start with acme or square threaded rod and go from there"? I know I could make a moxon vise out of threaded rods or clamps but the goal of this exercise is to cut coarse threads on the wood lathe the by product here is some screws for the vise. First goal cut threads on the  wood lathe(I have a metal working lathe I could cut this on but I want to do it on the wood lathe :)) secondary goal is make moxon vise.

Comment: Never mind, if you're set on doing this on your woodworking lathe then my comment is completely outside of what you're looking for.

Comment: @Graphus... dude... I just looked at those to bench clamps in your linked image. What a genius idea!! I might have to make me some o' dem! I might even ask a question about "options for a non-standard bench vice" just so you can post it where everyone can see it!

Comment: @FreeMan, I was sooo intending to make one of these, before I saw that (for occasional use) you could just use standard UNC or metric threads to make a reasonable vice.... For a twin-screw, since in practical use you only need to loosen one of the two screws the majority of the time, it's really very quick even with the 'slow' thread compared to acme or square. The YT channel Wortheffort, that's what he built his super-budget-friendly vice around to add to his beginner's bench and he's very efficient when he uses it for subsequent projects; check it out if you haven't seen any episodes.